Quick start demo fails saying it finds MySQL 3 (less than the required) while I have MySQL 5 installed
I am an old developer, now retired and only familiar with Drupal 7, who wants to enter Drupal 11.
Great gap, so rather than trying to update my previous installation, I chose to directly install Drupal 11 as a totally separated new application.
I followed the instructions given by the Drupal Quick Start Command page, for Windows.

Step #1 - install PHP: I already had PHP 8.3.3 installed, so I did nothing
Step #2 - get Drupal: I choosed option A, so first I successfully installed composer 2.8.1, then successfully installed Drupal 11 using the given command composer create-project drupal/recommended-project drupal && cd drupal
Step #3 - quick start: I used the given command php -d memory_limit=256M web/core/scripts/drupal quick-start demo_umami, which failed like follows:


4/17 [======>---------------------]
Set up database
In install.core.inc line 989:
Resolve all issues below to continue the installation. For help configuring your database server, see the installation handbook, or contact your hosting provider.
The database server version 3.40.0 is less than the minimum required version 3.45

This is doubly incomprehensible:

my current MySQL version is 5.7.17, so how the system can imagine I have a 3.40.0 one?
anyway, it says a 3.45 version is required, while another Drupal page says:


Drupal 11.0 will require PHP 8.3 and MySQL 8.0

I had previously noticed this requirement and I planned to update MySQL when needed, but now I hesitate, seeing how it is pretty incoherent.

I am 99% sure that error refers to the version of SQLite on the system, not of MySQL. That demo site uses SQLite.

Oh! Yes, it explains the two contradictions. Thanks.
